# Add "Select top 1000" command to toolbar in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL server management studio (2008) quite a lot these days. If it had a "Select top 1000" command in the toolbar,(or a shortcut key) it would make my life a lot easier. Is there any way i can do it. I tried looking in the customize dialog, but cant find that command there.

Comment: Are you after column names or data or ...?
Red-gate SQL Prompt can help with the data as it pops up table schemas and so on. I reuqested that they add the feature you're on about, but I'm not sure if/when this will be implemented

Answer (score 3):

The steps are as follows:

- Navigate to Tools, Options, Environment, Keyboard
- Choose one of the query shortcuts not in use
- Where it says 'Stored Procedure' enter:

> select top 1000 * from

- You'll have to open a new query window for the shortcut changes to take affect
- Press your shortcut when selecting a table name

Comment: How would you do this in SSMS 17.4?

Answer (score 0):

SQUirreL, a cross-platform SQL client/database browser, has a checkbox for this (which defaults to "top 100).

Answer (score 0):

Tools, Options, Query Execution, General, SET ROWCOUNT. The default is zero = no limits.

SET ROWCOUNT is environment specific for all queries. SELECT TOP is per query.